# php curl returning blank data if used inside function

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I'm new to php. I'm trying to write a simple plugin that calls the api and returns a JSON response.

When I write the same code outside function, I get a JSON response. But the issue is when I use the function below, it doesn't return any value.. The page seems blank

Here is my function

```
function getDOTD(){
try{        
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $baseUrl."offers/v1/dotd/json");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Fk-Affiliate-Id:'.get_option('affiliate_id'),'Fk-Affiliate-Token:'.get_option('affiliate_token')));       
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    print($result);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n"; abort;
}
}
```

i have also tried to use return instead of print() but that too didn't worked.
this is how i call my function -

```
print(getDOTD());
```

Any help appreciated... TIA :)

Comment: Try changing `print($result);` to `return $result;`

Comment: i tried that too but it isn't working.. :(

Comment: Then I whould try to put `die();` right after `print($result);` to see if it's actually getting any result. Also do `var_dump($baseUrl);` inside the function.

Comment: wow i did var_dump($baseUrl); inside function and it returned NULL.. how is that i am defining $baseurl above my function

Comment: Just use `function getDOTD($baseUrl)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know how the variables scope works.

From the PHP Documentation

```
<?php
$a = 1; /* global scope */
function test(){
    echo 'local variable: ' . $a; /* reference to local scope variable // NULL */
}
test();
?>
```

To be able to access to the global scope you need to use the `global` keyword inside your function

```
<?php
$a = 'Hello World'; /* global scope */
function test(){
    global $a;
    echo 'global variable: ' . $a; /* reference to global scope variable // Hello World */
}
test();
?>
```

More info about the [variables scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)